# Dialer, Contacts and Messenger apps closing automatically in Oneplus X

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, crashes, system-apps, oneplus-x

Since a week, the Dialer, Contacts and Messenger apps have been crashing frequently whenever I try to open them. But after few hours after crashing somehow they start working normally. I have tried clearing the data and cache, tried resetting the phone, installing third-party apps for making phone calls and messages. But even those apps are crashing, if they are related to making phone calls and messages. I tried wiping the data and making a hard reset, but still the problem persists. So please help me solving this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had one plus 1 back in 2015 and it was really good but with age it started showing similar issues. I took it to the service center and they said the problem is with OS and they are going to format and reinstall.

Luckily i got the upgraded OS but it didn't really help me, after 1 month i started facing the same problem then i visited the service center again and finally they end up replacing my handset to a new one.